# Google TV Video player not playing videos

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, google-tv

I'm having issues playing a video on Google TV Emulator.

I downloaded the google-tv-videoplayer example for Google TV Emulator.
I have eclipse set up with Ubuntu (KVM), emulator loads fine, no errors.

I have not altered the code heavily, only added missing resources, and changed the JSON request url. The problem is, it doesnt seem to want to play any videos. I read somewhere in the bug reports that it had some problems playing videos, so I was hoping someone can provide some insight or some direction of how to solve this problems, or what my options can be.

Just to brief, It gets the direct URL of the videofile from a JSON response, all parsing and functionality seems to be fine on the emulator, I see all my json entries being displayed properly, and I have checked my weblogs to make sure the JSON's video URLs that are playing are correct and not returning 404. I am returning a raw file, I do not know if maybe the emulator expects some HTTP header in the response...

The Google TV emulator is having problems playing MPG, MPEG, MP4, WMV files that I've tested so far. The only video it seemed to play was a m4v type file. Although, when that video played, the resolution looked distorted, I have a screenshot attached showing what happens. It seems to be a larger video frame that got stuck in the background, then a smaller video actually playing on top of it... (Check image link)

http://priceswagger.com/src/priceswagger_stuff/images/sshelp.png

Any ideas, please?
Thanks

Comment: To make it easier to debug, please add links to your JSON feed and video file urls.

Answer (score 1):

Videos rarely work on the Emulator.

Comment: Thanks! i've noticed much better playback on the actual device